# How to handle onclick events on the compound drawables of a TextInputEditText?

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputedittext

How can one detect click events on compound drawables of a `TextInputEditText`?

Comment: note to reviewers: Please don't marks as duplicate. There's a close duplicate for EditText, but the top answer is incorrect and unusable. And if any of the many answers are correct,  I can't find one. Question retargeted specifically at TextInputEditText because compound drawables are import for correct implementaton of Material Design. And hopefully, people who need this will find it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following overriden version of `TextInputEditText`, and call `setOnDrawableClickedListener`.

You may fare better if you set your drawable at the end of the edit text than at the start, because the current version of `TextInputLayout` produces fairly ugly results when the drawable is at the start.

Sample layout is given further down. (Note the use of `android:drawablePadding="10dp"` particularly).

Code is for androidx, but you can backport to AppCompat trivially.

```
package com.twoplay.netplayer.controls;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

public class TextInputEditTextEx extends TextInputEditText {
    private OnDrawableClickedListener onDrawableClickedListener;

    public TextInputEditTextEx(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }


    public TextInputEditTextEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TextInputEditTextEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            private Rect hitBounds = new Rect();
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();

                int hitDrawable = -1;

                if (x < getCompoundPaddingLeft())
                {
                    hitDrawable = 0;
                    hitBounds.set(0,0,getCompoundPaddingLeft(),getHeight());
                }
                if (x > getWidth()-getCompoundPaddingRight())
                {
                    hitDrawable = 2;
                    hitBounds.set(getCompoundPaddingRight(),0,getWidth(),getHeight());
                }
                if (hitDrawable != -1)
                {
                    int action = event.getAction();
                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                    {
                        onDrawableClicked(hitDrawable,hitBounds);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void onDrawableClicked(int i, Rect bounds) {
        if (onDrawableClickedListener != null)
        {
            onDrawableClickedListener.onDrawableClicked(this,i,bounds);
        }
    }

    public interface OnDrawableClickedListener {
        void onDrawableClicked(View v, int drawable, Rect bounds);
    }

    public void setOnDrawableClickedListener(OnDrawableClickedListener listener)
    {
        this.onDrawableClickedListener = listener;
    }

}
```

Sample layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/playlist_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/playlist_name" >

    <com.twoplay.netplayer.controls.TextInputEditTextEx
        android:id="@+id/playlist_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_more_horiz_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```